# sum data using checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js

below in my Vue JS code, i wanted to sum input data if it's checked in checkbox only, for ex (sum input entered by user instTwo + instThr  if they're checked only) and if it's not checked it shouldn't be sum

is there a way in Vue JS to sum data below if it's checked only ?

```js
data() {
        return {
           checkPayment: true,
            checkPayment2: true,
            checkPayment3: true,
            checkPayment4: true,
   
   }},
```

```html
<p> amount No.1 </p>
  <div class="inst-input justify-content-center mt-3">

 <input v-model="instTwo" class="paid-input"  required />

<b-form-checkbox id="checkboxs-2" v-model="checkPayment" name="checkbox-2" unchecked-value="false">
  
</b-form-checkbox>
</div>

<p> amount No.2 </p>
 <div class="inst-input justify-content-center mt-3">
 <input v-model="instThr" class="paid-input"  required />

 <b-form-checkbox id="checkbox" v-model="checkPayment2" name="checkbox-1" unchecked-value="false">
</b-form-checkbox>
</div>

<p> amount No.3</p>
 <div class="inst-input justify-content-center mt-3">
 <input v-model="instFour" class="paid-input"  required />

 <b-form-checkbox id="checkbox" v-model="checkPayment3" name="checkbox-1" unchecked-value="false">
</b-form-checkbox>
</div>

<p> amount No.4 </p>
 <div class="inst-input justify-content-center mt-3">
 <input v-model="instFive" class="paid-input"  required />

 <b-form-checkbox id="checkbox" v-model="checkPayment4" name="checkbox-1" unchecked-value="false">
</b-form-checkbox>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you post the data? It's a bit hard to understand what you're doing there if you only provide us with have of the code you're talking about.

Comment: @shaedrich i updated my question above, i'm posting data in `PostPayment` .. the `paid_amount` : this.totpaid.toString()` is posting the total amount that has `is_paid=true` which i'm setting from the checkbox and my problem is totpaid is summing data from prev result .. i wanted to sum data if the box is checked like before i post to API